# Not Able to Disable a div On Click by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please take a look at this code and let me know why I am not able to Disable the div on clicking

```js
$("#test").on("click", function(){
    alert("You Clicked On Div.");
});

$("#test").prop("disabled", true);
$("#test").attr("disabled", 'disabled');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"> Click Me </div>
```

Comment: What is expected result of `disabled` attribute set to `true` ?, removal of `click` event listener ?

Comment: If that's your code, it's because there's nothing inside the click handler disabling anything, it's outside the handler, and a DIV can't really be disabled ?

Comment: I'm guessing what the OP wants is to have the click event not do anything because the event has been disabled already outside of the click handler.

Comment: @abalter, yes I am looking for that

Comment: What I am looking for is disabling the div to handle any event

Comment: That's not how you remove an event handler, you'd do that with `off()` in jQuery, but then it just makes no sense to add the event handler to begin with ?

Comment: _"What I am looking for is disabling the div to handle any event "_ Is requirement to disable all attached events on `click`, or only `click` event ?

Comment: Right. Just use `.on(...)` and `.off(...)`. However, it is strange that what the OP is doing isn't working. Check out this fiddle. The element reports to be "disabled", but the click event still fires.  http://jsfiddle.net/abalter/dmxa106o/

Comment: @abalter Why would `click` handler not be called ?

Comment: @abalter - and again, you can't disable a DIV, and adding the disabled property does nothing for jQuery's event handlers on an element that doesn't really support a disabled property.

Comment: Doesn't this `disabled` DOM property make things unclickable? According to the page, "Disabled elements are usually rendered in gray by default in browsers." http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_disabled.asp

Comment: Perhaps it only applies to form controls, but that is not explicitly stated.

Comment: @abalter - a more proper resource than w3fools, like say the [**HTML5 specification**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/disabled-elements.html) clearly states what elements can be disabled, and DIV's aren't part of that list.

Answer (score 2):

If you are wanting to "turn off" the click, you need to use [.off](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

```
$("#test").on("click", function(){
    alert("You Clicked On Div.");
    $("#test").off("click");
});
```

If you click once, the alert will fire. Next time it will not as all "click" events have been unbound from any element matching "#test".